# Storing Active/Inactive Timestamps

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

I'm running a ruby on Rails app with a PostgreSQL backend, and am wondering what the standard way is to store a series of timestamps. The situation is that I have a model with a boolean `status` attribute. I need to keep track of the dates/times at which this attribute changes, because I need to keep track of the time periods during which `status` is set to `true`. My experience with this kind of problem is seriously lacking, and I'm not sure what the best practice is for doing this kind of thing in a scalable way. The two approaches I've considered are:

1) JSONifying text. I was thinking about taking an array that might look like the following:

```
[
  { 
      start: "20150131103045",
      end: "20150228103045"
  },
  { 
      start: "20150531103045",
      end: "20150628103045"
  },
]
```

I would then JSONify this array and store it in a `text` column.

2) Creating a separate table which would have columns of `model_id`, `status`, and `time_recorded` attributes, and then simply creating an entry every time the model's `status` attribute is updated.

Which of these approaches is more sound? Something to consider here is that this data is probably not going to be read very frequently - 95% of the time, it will just be new data that gets written to the database.

Option 1) seems to be less heavy-handed to me, but it would also be a bigger pain to read the data and sort through it when I need to. Option 2) would store that data in a way that's easier to work with, and the pre-existing data would never need to be read/updated, but the table could potentially get very large, very quickly. The kicker is that I have to do this with several models in my app, so making hasty decision and implementing a bad architecture from the start could be rather annoying to deal with later.

What are the pros and cons of these two approaches? Is either of these obviously a better solution than the other? Or is there another, better option that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You have to consider when doing updates in a row, Postgres will in background create another version of that row, with the new data on it, and mark the old one to be reused when a vacuum is done in that table. As you can see, this will cause a lot of "vacuum effort" (read it as high disk/IO effort). It will be even worst if the row's data does not fit in a single data page. In that case, there is a "toast" table to be vacuumed too.

---

**Option 2:**

**That looks to me the better approach**, because once the row is inserted, you will never update it. And data looks to be small enough to fit a single data page (no need a toast table). If you use correct indexes, you will not have performance issues. Postgres can handle easily millions of records.

Also, you can use of the [patitioning table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) technique. If your table has billions and billions of history records, you could "split" it into several other tables (one per month, for example), where the indexes will be pretty small per table and will run really fast. Everything is done in background, so your application will see only the "main" table, and Postgres will deal with all the other spliced table automatically.

If you need to retrieve your data in a JSON format, it will be easy too. You can just create a view (or a function if you wish) where that column with "start/end" times will be mounted in a JSON array format (using postgres 9.3 and above).